# Blender 2.73a won't start

Tags: performance

Downloaded the newest version, 2.73a, twice.  Each time the download seems to go well, but when i start the program it opens only for a second then closes.  It does this repeatedly.  Using Win8.1.  Had no trouble with v2.72, i used it from when it first appeared until yesterday.

Anyone know what my problem is and how to fix it?

..thanks,

gmo

Comment: I know of at least one person who only managed to get 2.7x series working after updating graphics card drivers. This isn't mentioned in the proposed duplicate thread.